# SQL Tabl1.Field(string) = Table2.Field(string) when they're not equals is returning a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

I'm joining two tables as seen below

```
select *
from Table1 t1
inner join Table t2
on t1.pKey = t2.pKey
and t1.Field1 = t2.Field1
```

t1.Field1 equals "SYS" and t2.Field1 equals "SYS-(U)"

Why is this returning a row?

Comment: Do not tag indiscriminately. SQL Sever and MySQL use different sql dialects. And rather than force the reader to guess, please post DDL for the tables involved and something to convince us that Field1 in the 2 tables contains the values you indicate. Are you certain that you did not accidentally use the wrong alias in join logic (e.g., on t1.Field1 = t1.Field1)?

Comment: The join is on t1.pKey = t2.pKey ... I know it's sample code but are you trying to join on the primary keys of both tables?

Comment: are all the rows for column Field1 in Table1 equals "SYS" and "SYS-(U)" in Table2? try to run SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM table1, and also SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM table2? check the result.